# SQL table constraint limit number of same domain < 5

Tags: oracle, database-design

I have a table "Applies" with one of its attribute "applicantNum".

Is there a way to set a constraint to check the value inside a domain has less than 5 repeated value?

E.g.

```
insert into applies(applicantNum) values ('s12345');<-- 1st insertion
insert into applies(applicantNum) values ('s12345');<-- 2nd insertion
insert into applies(applicantNum) values ('s12345');<-- 3rd insertion
insert into applies(applicantNum) values ('s12345');<-- 4th insertion
insert into applies(applicantNum) values ('s12345');<-- 5th insertion
insert into applies(applicantNum) values ('s12345'); <-- error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to normalize the database, or you'll have to use a trigger. There is a method of doing what you want, it can be done with `F671, “Subqueries in CHECK constraints”` however Oracle doesn't implement them. For that, you'll have to turn to everyone's favorite database, [Microsoft Access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6196783/124486).

To normalize create a table like this with a check constraint on the amount of attempts, then increase the amount of attempts. The `CHECK` constraint will resist incrementing past 5.

```
CREATE TABLE applicant (
  applicantNum     int        PRIMARY KEY,
  applicantentries smallint   CHECK ( applicantentries < 5 )
);
```